# browser doesn't store HTTPOnly cookie?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm sending a HTTPOnly cookie with JWT from server(node/express) to client(vue), and the browser doesn't store the cookie, I have tried with three different browsers chromium Brave and Firefox (just in case lol), in Firefox with DEV Tools -> Network -> cookies tab  I can see the token is sent, but the browser never stores it.

I'm in localhost...

```
const token = jwt.sign(
    {
      id: newUser._id
    },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    {
      expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
    }
     );

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') cookieOptions.secure = 
 true;

   const cookieOptions = {
        expires: new Date(
       Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 
           * 1000
        ),

     httpOnly: true
    };
   res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of httpOnly cookies is to not be visible to browser-based scripts.  So the browser stores them, but doesn't share them with scripts it runs.